# Java ldap authentication issue

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I'm trying to have my custom java application use our Active Directory Server for authentication but I cannot get it to work for some reason.  Can anyone see why this is?  Here is my method below:

```
private boolean authenticate(String serverName, String userId, String password) throws NamingException {
    DirContext ctx = null;
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable(11);
    boolean b = false;
    try {
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
        "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://servername.org:389");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid="+ userId +",ou=All Users,dc=site,dc=org");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        System.out.println("before context");
        // If there isn't a naming exception then the user is authenticated. Return true
        ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        //The user is authenticated.
        b = true;
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("the user is not authenticated return false");
        b = false;
    }finally{
        if(ctx != null)
            ctx.close();
    }
    return b;
}
```

Result:

```
[12/14/11 16:27:47:746 CST] 0000001f SystemErr     R
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, vece
```

Comment: what happens? can you post a stack trace?

Comment: I get an ldap error code 49 which is an authentication error.  However, the credentials I'm supplying are correct.  I'm able to login to my windows machine and other servers with it.

Comment: does your ldap requires encryption? do you use any specific connection parameters, that you may find important to share? Otherwise it's just guessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this way?

```
//...
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn="+ userId +",ou=All Users,dc=site,dc=org");
//...
```

Also replace

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable(11);
```

with

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
```

Comment: Thanks!!  This did the trick...I knew it had to be something simple.